# Import/Load CSS or JS file from File Attachments instead of Static Resource in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, js

I have different css files for each record, which will be stored as a file(ContentVersion). I want to load that css in lwc. But getting this error.

Refused to apply style from '' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I know we can load the js or css files from static resources, but is it possible to load it from files instead of static resource as the css/js files will be dynamic?

Comment: To understand exactly what you are doing can you put some code?
Does your styles start with a comment? If yes please remove the comment and try again.

Comment: You'll need to set the ContentVersion's FileType correctly.

Comment: @sfdcfox FileType is CSS, I am fetching the VersionData from apex method. Below is the sample code.

Promise.all([
                        loadStyle(this, data.VersionData)
                    ]);

Still no luck. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter must always be a URL. It cannot be plain text that was loaded/parsed directly. You'll want to construct a URL in Apex using Url.getFileFieldUrl:

```
String fileURL = 
  URL.getFileFieldURL(
    recordId ,
    'VersionData');
```

Then load that resulting URL in your loadStyle call.